# authlogic & iOS, should I be saving password or tokens, and how?

Tags: ios, authlogic

I'm very new to writing web apps and writing iPhone apps. I have a simple web app ready to go which uses authlogic to have users sign in / register.

I want to allow users of the iPhone app to sign in and register. In order to do this, I am planning to use ASIHTTP. I am doing that based off of this stackoverflow topic: [Authlogic and iPhone app login](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5481874/authlogic-and-iphone-app-login)

Is that the best of way of going about it or are there better/easier methods of doing it? I wanted to try to use ObjectiveResource, but unfortunately I cannot access the iphoneonrails.com website.

Now, assuming I can get the system hooked up, how do I save passwords on the device? I want the user to have to log in just once. Do I save some authlogic token or should I be saving the username/password to the keychain in iOS? To me it seems to make sense to save the single use token.

Answer (score -9, accepted):

You can use NSUserDefaults to store the simple information like username and passwords

```
NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

[prefs setObject:username.text forKey:@"username"];
[prefs setObject:password.text forKey:@"password"];
[prefs synchronize];
```

For Retrieving the data you can use

```
NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

NSString *u = [prefs stringForKey:@"username"];
NSString *p = [prefs stringForKey:@"password"];
```

**Update:**

There is a better way to **store credentials** in Cocoa, please see @Pius Uzamere answer for storing credentials. Please see this link for example code: http://iosdevelopertips.com/core-services/using-keychain-to-store-username-and-password.html

Comment: For security you can always take the MD5Hash and then store the confidential info like passwords and CC info. But its for normal persistance storage rather then getting into deep SQLlit stuff

Comment: Negative votes would be because it's not a secure way to save sensitive data. See Pius Uzamere's answer which recommends using the Keychain to store such information. That's exactly what the Keychain is there for.

Answer (score 15):

The accepted answer is not secure. You should not save sensitive information in NSUserDefaults; use the Keychain instead.

See: [iOS: How to store username/password within an app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6972092/ios-how-to-store-username-password-wihtin-an-app)